# Casting List object in C#

Tags: c#, casting

I need to cast a List object to another List object which is an interface

```
public class THold : IHold
{..}
```

Here, IHold is the interface.

I want to do this:

```
List<THold> hold = new List<THold>();
List<IHold> test = hold;
```

Comment: @Fred - Where's the fun in that?

Comment: @Fred: You may be right, but this isn't the place to register suggestions. Post it on meta.stackoverflow.com - that way, you might get something changed.

Answer (score 6):

The closest you're going to come is:

```
List<IHold> test = hold.Cast<IHold>().ToList();
```

The problem is that a direct cast doesn't exist. What if I had the following:

```
public class THold : IHold { /* ... */ }

public class UHold : IHold { /* ... */ }
```

And then:

```
List<THold> holds = new List<THold>();
List<IHold> iholds = (List<IHold>) holds;

iholds.Add(UHold);
```

Obviously `UHold` implements the `IHold` interface but also obviously can't be added to the list of `THold` objects.

Comment: IHold, UHold, we all hold for IHold!  (sorry I couldn't resist)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `List<>` cannot be created in non-generic form; I'm guessing you lost the angle brackets somewhere in writing your post.

Anyway, I'm guessing you want to go from a `List<THold>` to a `List<IHold>`, or vice versa. Either way, the best option is the OfType() method of Linq:

```
List<THold> hold = new List<THold>();
//populate hold with items
List<IHold> test = hold.OfType<IHold>().ToList();
```

The `Cast<>()` method should also work, however I find whenever I try to use it to perform its stated task it never works right. Using Select() with a projection that casts each item will also work:

```
List<IHold> test = hold.Select(x=>(IHold)x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) article describes co- and contravariance which are the terms of what you describe.